# Strange .gitignore behavior for emacs temporary files

Tags: git, emacs

If I edit `new_file.txt` with emacs, there will be temporary files like `#new_file.txt#` and `.#new_file.txt` when the files are unsaved, and `new_file.txt~` when saved.
 I want to exclude these files. So I write my `.gitignore` like this:

```
#This is a comment line
*~
[#]*[#]
.\#*
```

And this works perfectly. But later I add some comment lines to it:

```
#This is a comment line
*~
[#]*[#]     # this is a comment
.\#*     # this is another comment
```

After a `git status`, I see both `#new_file.txt#` and `.#new_file.txt` are listed as the untracked files.

I think `.gitignore` may get confused at the `#` character as the beginning of the comment line. So I remove those two comment lines. However, after another `git status`, I still see  `#new_file.txt#` and `.#new_file.txt` listed as the untracked files.

I do :

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

as suggested in [".gitignore not working"](http://www.randallkent.com/development/gitignore-not-working), but it doesn't help.

Could someone please tell me what happened, and how to make `.gitignore` work as I wish? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comments on `.gitignore` files must be on their own line - any comment trailing a file pattern is interpreted as part of that pattern.

Move your comments to the line before the pattern, and it should return to its initial behavior.