# .gitignore regex for emacs temporary files

Tags: regex, git, emacs, gitignore

I'm trying to .gitignore emacs temporary/autosave files.  I'm using...

```
\.\#.*
```

in my .gitignore.

But `git add -A` run in a subfolder is still giving me:

```
#       new file:   .#make_collections.py
#       new file:   .#norm_collections.py
#       new file:   make_collections.py
#       new file:   norm_collections.py
```

even though

```
\.\#.*
```

is clearly getting the right file names and not the wrong ones when I [test it with a regex tester](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: What happens for `git add .` (without `-A`)?

Comment: It still picks up the ".#filenames" for adds but now also wouldn't catch removes.

Comment: Strictly speaking, are .gitignore patterns actually regexes?  Should we take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498059?

Answer (score 36):

You can also instruct emacs to save the autosave files in a different directory altogether by setting the variable `auto-save-file-name-transforms`, I have this in my init file

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
          `((".*" ,(concat user-emacs-directory "auto-save/") t)))
```

This instructs emacs to store the auto-saves inside the `auto-save` folder in the user-emacs-directory (usually `~/.emacs.d`).

To save backup files in a different directory set the variable `backup-directory-alist`, the following will save backup files inside `backups` folder in the user-emacs-directory

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `(("." . ,(expand-file-name
                 (concat user-emacs-directory "backups")))))
```

Comment: This is the solution to my problem I will use going forward.

Answer (score 21):

gitignore doesn't use regular expressions. Instead it uses shell glob patters. The [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) tells you two things important for this situation:

```
Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for
consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag.
```

and

```
A line starting with # serves as a comment. Put a backslash ("\")
in front of the first hash for patterns that begin with a hash.
```

This means that the pattern you want to use is simply `.#*`.

Now the second pattern that matov mentioned, `#*`, doesn't do anything as it is treated as a comment by git. Hence me quoting that second sentence from the man page.

Comment: It *does not* works for temp files like `#myfile#`. The solution is the one below : `\#*#`

Answer (score 17):

Emacs autosave files are ignored with

```
\#*#
```

Comment: I have added this line to my .gitignore, the files are still appearing.

Comment: Did you try this [#]*[#]

Comment: yes, that is also in my .gitignore.  And it does exclude `#filename.py#`. just not `.#filename.py#` with the dot in front.

Comment: Still there, which is what's very odd.

Comment: .[#]*[#] I tried this one with my gitignore file and it is working.

Answer (score 12):

files are ignored with:

`\#*\#
.\#*`

Answer (score 3):

If you want an easy way to ignore files, you can also use http://www.gitignore.io which helps create useful .gitignore files for your project.

Here is the emacs template: https://www.gitignore.io/api/emacs

There is also [documentation](https://www.gitignore.io/docs) demonstrating how to run `gi` from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

To suppress the temporary Emacs files appearing on `git status` globally, you can do the following:

1. **Configure git to use a global excludesfile**

   Since this is a common problem, `git` has a [specific solution](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to that:

   > Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by core.excludesFile in the user’s ~/.gitconfig

   ```
   git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
   ```
2. **Create the respective file**

   ```
    cd
    touch .gitignore_global
   ```
3. **Paste the following [template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Emacs.gitignore) into the file**

   ```
   # -*- mode: gitignore; -*-
   *~
   \#*\#
   /.emacs.desktop
   /.emacs.desktop.lock
   *.elc
   auto-save-list
   tramp
   .\#*

   # Org-mode
   .org-id-locations
   *_archive

   # flymake-mode
   *_flymake.*

   # eshell files
   /eshell/history
   /eshell/lastdir

   # elpa packages
   /elpa/

   # reftex files
   .rel

   # AUCTeX auto folder
   /auto/

   # cask packages
   .cask/
   dist/

   # Flycheck
   flycheck_*.el

   # server auth directory
   /server/

   # projectiles files
   .projectile

   # directory configuration
   .dir-locals.el

   # network security
   /network-security.data
   ```
4. **Watch git do its magic! :)**