# how to stop kitchen from using *.*~ files? chefignore?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I use emacs to do my development.  Emacs will make backups of edited files with a tilde ~.  When I run

```
kitchen converge
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/lcd_haproxy/attributes/default.rb~
```

Notice the ~ on the end of the file.

Now if I run the following command kitchen converge will work with out error:

```
find ./ -name *.*\~ | xargs rm
```

Looking in chefignore if see the following:

```
# EDITORS #
###########
...snip...
*~
```

That should ignore files ending with ~.  Also found in the chefignore file is this explaination:

```
# Put files/directories that should be ignored in this file when uploading
# to a chef-server or supermarket.
```

So this might not be the place to stop a kitchen converge from using unwanted files.

Does anyone know how to stop kitchen from using *.*~ files?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175365/gitignore-regex-for-emacs-temporary-files which explains how you can set emacs to save back files in a different folder. That should help since it won't mess up your kitchen command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Test Kitchen doesn't actually know about chefignore files (it's on our list though). What gets uploaded is mostly up to [the cookbooks_files_glob setting](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/0cd59179a153f67aa1e97e769c0a095da6bc3ef4/lib/kitchen/provisioner/chef_base.rb#L64).